# Convert (flatten) multiple header Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following Pandas dataframe taken from an Excel file [(link to the Excel file)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1B-i-wWeDfn4-tTnEcKWeEEkJwzB56wWb/view?usp=sharing)

I would like to flatten the Excel table with Pandas by converting the current headers (two first rows) to dataframe columns. This is where I want to get to:

```
segment unit    category    sub_category    value
seg1    kg      cat01       sub_cat_1.1     1
seg2    kg      cat01       sub_cat_1.1     2
seg1    kg      cat01       sub_cat_1.2     3
seg2    kg      cat01       sub_cat_1.2     
seg1    kg      cat02       sub_cat_2.1     4
seg2    kg      cat02       sub_cat_2.1     5
```

What I did so far is the folowing, but it doesn't work as expected:

```
import pandas as pd

_file_name = "stackoverflow_excel_data_example.xlsx"
df = pd.read_excel(_file_name,  header=[0,1]).sort_index()
df = df.stack()
print(df)
```

Does anyone know how to convert a custom -kind of pivot- table to a flat dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No real magic here, you need to reorganize your `MultiIndex` before:

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('segment', ''), ('unit', '')] +
                                       df.columns[2:].to_list(),
                                       names=df.columns[1])
```

At this point, `df` looks like:

```
>>> df
category     segment unit       cat01                   cat02
sub_category              sub_cat_1.1 sub_cat_1.2 sub_cat_2.1 sub_cat_2.1.1 sub_cat_2.1.2 sub_cat_2.1.3 sub_cat_2.1.4
0               seg1   kg           1         3.0           4           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN
1               seg2   kg           2         NaN           5           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN
```

Now you can apply transformation:

```
>>> df.set_index(["segment", "unit"]) \
      .stack(level=[0, 1])\
      .rename("value") \
      .reset_index()

  segment unit category sub_category  value
0    seg1   kg    cat01  sub_cat_1.1    1.0
1    seg1   kg    cat01  sub_cat_1.2    3.0
2    seg1   kg    cat02  sub_cat_2.1    4.0
3    seg2   kg    cat01  sub_cat_1.1    2.0
4    seg2   kg    cat02  sub_cat_2.1    5.0
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

```py
df = pd.read_excel(..., header=[0, 1])
df = (
    df
    .iloc[:, 2:]
    .set_index(df.iloc[:, 0])
    .set_index(df.iloc[:, 1], append=True)
    .stack([0, 1])
    .rename_axis(["segement", "quantity", "category", "sub_category"])
    .rename("value")
    .reset_index()
)
```

The result for the provided example input is
[image]

Comment: Good answer really. +1. add `.rename('value').reset_index()` (and swap `category` and `sub_category`)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As mentionned by @Corralien I had to add ```.rename('value').reset_index()```